# UICollectionView datasource understanding issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have confused with datasource of UIColectionView and I really need help here.

I have array with objects `[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6"]`

So I need to display them

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I have found this code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return  noOfItem/ noOfSection;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return noOfSection;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellRecipe";    
     collectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  ;

    Employee *emp = [array_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * noOfSection + indexPath.row];
    cell.name.text = emp.name;
    cell.image.image = emp.thumbImg;

    return cell;
}
```

but I think it is not good use noOfItem/ noOfSection

so for example if I have 20 objects and 3 items per section

I got this error

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 20 beyond bounds [0 .. 19]'
```

because each my section has 3 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to an array containing [@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6"]

You don't need this method :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
```

Now do this :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arrayName count];
}
```

Now you need to set the size of cell so that each row can have 3 items. You can either set the size of cell using storyboard or you can use this method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout  *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you aren't quite approaching UICollectionView in the correct way.

Sections are meant to be separate sections of content, not the number of rows.
Items in section is meant to return the number of items for a given section.

In your example I would do it like this:

```
/**
 *  Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.employees = @[[[Employee alloc] init], [[Employee alloc] init], [[Employee alloc] init], [[Employee alloc] init], [[Employee alloc] init]];
}

/**
 *  Asks the data source for the number of sections in the collection view.
 *
 *  @param  collectionView              An object representing the collection view requesting this information.
 *
 *  @return The number of sections in collectionView.
 */
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

/**
 *  Asks the data source for the cell that corresponds to the specified item in the collection view.
 *
 *  @param  collectionView              An object representing the collection view requesting this information.
 *  @param  indexPath                   The index path that specifies the location of the item.
 *
 *  @return A configured cell object. You must not return nil from this method.
 */
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellRecipe";    
    collectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Employee *employee = self.items[indexPath.item];
    cell.name.text = employee.name;
    cell.image.image = employee.thumbImg;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.items.count;
}
```

Comment: so the employee this is another code I want to display 3 items in the section 

so but sometimes it can be not 21 items it can be 20 items in my array so it means i need to check how many items uicolection view has to display for the last section. because it will be 2 items for the last section and per 3 items for each other section. am I right?

Comment: @Infinity James : indexpath.row is not used in collection view. In collectionview indexpath.item is used instead of indexpath.row.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander : 
    123
    456
There are not 2 sections in it. There is just 1 section in it. The cells arranges themselves in this form as in flowlayout. You just need to manage the size of the cells to show 3 items in a particular row.

Comment: hm I supposed sections work in another way thank you )

Answer (score 0):

True. You don't really need numberOfSections... as you can solve this with sizing of cells (autolayout is your friend). If using the `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`, you need to catch that the last section only has two items. You didn't include how you calculate noOfSection.

In the numberOfItems... method, you can do this:

```
if (section == noOfSection) {
    return noOfItem % noOfSection; // Finding the remainder with modulo
} else {
    return noOfItem / noOfSection;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but believe it should work.